# combinatorial optimization - maximalize profit when creating furniture

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

Some firm is supplied with large wooden panels. These panels are cut to required pieces. To make for example bookshelf, they have to cut pieces from the large panel. In most cases, the pig panel is not used from 100%, there will be some loss, some remainder pieces, which can not be used. So to minimize the loss, they have to find optimal layout of separate pieces on big panel/panels. I think this is called "two dimensional rectangle bin packing problem".

Now it is getting more interesting.

Not all panels are the same, they can have slightly different tone. Ideal bookshelf is made from pieces all cut from one panels or multiple panels with same color tone. But bookshelf can be produced in different qualities (ideal one; one piece with different tone; two pieces..., three different color plates used; etc...). Each quality has its own price. (the superior in quality the more expensive).

Now we have some wooden panels in stock and request to some furnitures (e.g. 100 bookshelves). The goal is to maximize the profit (e.g. create some ones in ideal quality and some in less quality to keep material loss low).

How to solve this problem? How to combine it with bin packing problem? And hints, papers/articles would be appreciated. I know I can minimize/maximize some function and inequalities with integer linear programming, but I really do not know how to solve this.

(please, do not consider the real scenerio, when for example would be the best to create only ideal ones... imagine, that loss from remaining material is X money per cm^2 and Y is the price for specific product quality and that X and Y can be "arbitrary")

Comment: This seems similar to the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) mixed with a profit maximization problem. You'll probably need a MIP to solve it completely, if that's even possible; otherwise I think you will need heuristics to get an approximation solution.

Comment: The solution depends on the price you can charge the consumer for each type. This sort of problem is covered in economics, start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_curve as an intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give an idea of how these problems are solved and why yours is particularly difficult.

In a typical optimization problem, you want to maximize or minimize a function (e.g. energy) with respect to a set number of variables (e.g. length).  For example, how long should a spring be in order to minimize the stored energy.  The answer is just a number, the equilibrium length of the spring.  Another example would be "what price should we set our product to maximize profit?"  (Too expensive and no-one will buy anything; too cheap and you won't cover your costs.)  Again, the answer is just a number, the optimal price.  Optimizations like that are handled with ordinary calculus.

A much more difficult optimization problem is where the answer isn't a number, but a function, like a shape.  An example is: what shape will a hanging chain make in order to minimize its gravitational potential energy.  Or: what shape should we cut out of these boards in order to maximize profit?  This type of problem is solved using variational calculus, which is very difficult.

In any case, when solving optimization problems numerically, there are a few basic steps to follow.  First you have to define a function, for example profit(cuts,params) that you want to maximize with respect to some variables 'cuts', with other parameters 'params' fixed.  'params' stores information like the amount and type of wood that you have, and the amount of money different type of furniture is worth.

The second step is to come up with a guess for the best set of cuts, we'll call it cuts_guess.  In order to do this you need to come up with an algorithm that will suggest a set of furniture you could actually make using the supplies that you have.  For example, if you can make at least one bookshelf from each board, then that could be your initial guess for the best way to use the wood.

The third phase is the optimization.  For the initialization, set cuts_best=cuts_guess and profit_best=profit_guess=profit(cuts_guess, params).  Then you need (an algorithm) to make small pseudo-random changes to 'cuts', and check if profit increases or decreases.  Record the best set of cuts that you find, and the corresponding profit.  Usually it's best if there some randomness involved, in order to explore the largest number of possibilities and not get 'stuck' on a poor choice.  You'll find examples of this if you look up 'Monte Carlo algorithm'.

Anyway, all of this will be very difficult for your problem.  It's easy how to come up with a guess for a variable (e.g. length), and then how to change that guess (e.g. increase or decrease the length a bit).  It's not at all obvious how to make a 'guess' for how to place a cut-out on a board, or how to make a small change.